# Laravel : create form show photo and edit form not showing photo

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

While dd($input) in create form show the following:

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "Q6xauvlFx0k61JDqFvo4FsJtr5Y9EbVX8V3Wwk8V"
  "blockquote" => "test block quote content"
  "name" => "test name"
  "description" => "test description"
  "photo" => UploadedFile {#267 ▶}
]
```

But dd($input) of edit form show the following

```
array:9 [▼
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "oDzfMvXiWMUzAr6zftnTZb9IVQCwWa2Tt2ZPBp6x"
  "photo" => "43-356x220.jpg"
  "blockquote" => "asf"
  "name" => "Af"
  "description" => "af"
  "files" => "1"
  "enctype" => "multipart/form-data"
  "data-toggle" => "validator"
]
```

So this cause image upload failure and

```
$image = Input::file('photo');
```

The above line return null. I want photo in that what should i do.

I think this work on method 'POST' in create and show different in method 'PATCH' in edit. How to achieve in edit?

Edit: My codes added

create.blade.php code

```
 {!! Form::open([
        'route' => 'MessageFromAlumniPresident.store', 'id' => 'formidda', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'data-toggle'=>'validator'
     ]) !!}

    @include('Admin.MessageFromAlumniPresident.create_edit_common')

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>


    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
$this->validate($request, [
            'blockquote' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();


        $hi = MessageFromAlumniPresident::create($input);

        //applicant photo
        $image = Input::file('photo');
        if($image === NULL){
            Session::flash('flash_message', 'Product Master successfully added!');

            //TODO: redirect to Party list page
            return redirect()->route('MessageFromAlumniPresident.index');
        }else{

            $filename = 'alumni_president'. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('/images/MessageFromAlumniPresident/'.$filename);
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);
        }
```

**This create works fine...**

edit.blade.php

```
 {!! Form::model($item, [
      'route' => ['MessageFromAlumniPresident.update', $item->id, 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'data-toggle'=>'validator']
      ]) !!}

    @include('Admin.MessageFromAlumniPresident.create_edit_common')

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller: for update **this is not working fine for photo**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $items = MessageFromAlumniPresident::findOrFail($id);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'blockquote' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();


        $image = Input::file('photo');

        $items->fill($input)->save();

        if($image === NULL){
            Session::flash('flash_message', 'Product Master successfully added!');

            //TODO: redirect to Party list page
            return redirect()->route('MessageFromAlumniPresident.index');
        }else{
            $path = public_path('/images/MessageFromAlumniPresident/alumni_president.jpg');

            \File::delete($path);

            $filename = 'alumni_president'. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('/images/MessageFromAlumniPresident/'.$filename);
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);
        }
```

Comment: What's the difference in your form in the file input? It seems the second one just sees a string as though you wrote `input type="text"`

Comment: Refer how to use file in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files

Comment: @Naincy create method in the controller return '"photo" => UploadedFile {#267 ▶}' so we can process but the upload method in the controller gives only the file name.

Comment: @arun show your code what you did?

Comment: @arun I understand so only I shared the link.... for saving you must want to retrieve path and extension that you can get from $path = $request->photo->path(); $extension = $request->photo->extension();
Not sure if you want something this or not

Comment: @Naincy im trying ur way

Comment: Add 'forms' using the HTML Way and not using the form-facades. Try this only if your edit and create forms are different. 
In order to upload files you should be setting the 'enc-type="multipart/form-data"' attribute on your form. Your input 'photo' shows a string where as it should be an UploadedFile Instance